# SharePoint 2019 Column Formatting - can't get it working

Tags: json, sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

I am trying to get column formatting using JSON working in my on premise SharePoint 2019 and I just cannot seem to get it working and I am struggling to find documentation for it. From what I have read Excel style JSON isn't supported in SharePoint 2019 but I am still struggling to get any formatting working at all.

The main thing that has lead me down this route is trying to get a basic text column with a URL in it to open in a new tab.

I have tried the following JSON but it doesn't work, no errors it just leaves it as a standard text field:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v1/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "@currentField"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try using this simple JSON once:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v1/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "https://www.google.com/"
  }
}
```

If it is showing correct hyperlink in SharePoint list column, make sure your list column contains valid web URL.

---

Also, make sure you are adding the JSON in **column formatting** settings and not in **view formatting** settings.

To open the column formatting pane, open the drop-down menu under a column heading the list view. Under **Column Settings**, choose **Format this column**:

[image]

Choose your column correctly, add/paste the JSON below and click "Save":

[image]